# subset dataframe by specific string entries in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have data in data frame format here ([data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CbfH1KvEGIrnDEBm17_i2gYBUqzohKz/view?usp=share_link)). I want to subset the data by using a specific string "Spatially clustered". So, the subset data will the data frame with all columns with entries that are "Spatially clustered". How can I do that? I have tried this

```
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion = data
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion_spatially_clustered = select(moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion, matches("clustered"))
```

moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion_spatially_clustered

also this one

```
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion_spatially_clustered = moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion[apply(moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion,1, function(x) any(grepl("dispersed", x))), ]
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_raw_pval_conclusion_spatially_clustered
```

However, the result is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
    select(where(~ any(str_detect(.x, "Spatially clustered"))))
```

-output

```
> dim(df2)
[1]     5 17989
> dim(df1)
[1]     5 23474
```